# Filtering or matching in nested list

Tags: list, nested, maps, elixir

My data structure was original a big Map. But I read that we should not use too big maps, to not run out of atoms. So my new data structure looks like that.

```
countries = [[{'name', 'Germany'}, {'code', 'DE'}], [{'name', 'Austria'}, {'code', 'AT'}]]
```

I want to make a  `filter_by/3` method, to filter this nested list for the country list by attributes `name` or `code`

Should I transform the Tuples to Maps or is there another way to filter this?

Comment: You have only two atoms for the keys, where is the problem? I would advise against optimising prematurely.

Comment: You can use as many atoms in your code as you want, because the same atom always points to the same name. They are efficient and very good even for big sets of data, like country codes or names. The only thing, you should avoid, is creating them dynamically (for example from user input), because they are not garbage collected. After long period of time, the atom table would grow bigger than your memory. Never be afraid of introducing new atom. It is cheap! Be afraid of using `list_to_atom/1`

Comment: You could also use HashDict, which is a dictionary like maps, but able to handle millions of keys. Also worth noting that Erlang 18 will likely feature big maps, which would make this whole discussion moot. :)

Comment: You may also want to look at this: https://github.com/pragdave/map_performance And I can't find it right now but I could swear I saw a good discussion about when to use which data structure somewhere in the Elixir docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a list of maps. Maps are very performant when retrieving elements, especially when the keys in a map are very few.

In your example:

```
countries = [%{name: "Germany", code: "DE"},
  %{name: "Austria", code: "AT"}]
```

Note that even if you'll use thousands of such maps in a list, you'll never run out of atoms since `:name` and `:code` will always be the only two allocated atoms (since each atom is exactly is value, so writing `:a` and `:a` is like writing `3` and `3`).

Once you have a similar list in place, you can filter it with a function like:

```
def filter_by(countries, key, value) do
  Enum.filter(countries, fn(country) -> country[key] == value end)
end

filter_by(countries, :code, "AT")
```